# Shopify: How to make a custom template editable in the theme editor?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am using the theme "Debut" and I've copied it to make a custom theme out of it.

Then, under "Edit code" I have create a new template for "blog".

Now, when I click on "Customize" button at my template, and the theme editor opens, I have a select box in the top bar where I can select the themes templates, and the pages I've created. But I can't find my custom blog template there, to edit it via the drag & drop editor.

How can I achieve this?

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should be looking at theme sections, here is a [link](https://www.shopify.ca/partners/blog/how-to-create-your-first-shopify-theme-section) to get you started!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you add any custom template for a blog, product, or collection, they are not available directly into the backend customizer in Shopify.

In backend default templates are available, you need to assign the template to a page, product or blog and then navigate to the desired page, collection or product and blog page into backend using customizer window and then you able to edit the sections and blocks that are added to custom template code.